# Summed area table vs Mipmap

Tags: graphics, mipmaps

Summed area table is a pre-filtering technique to avoid aliasing in texture map. I would like to know how it works and what are the advantages and disadvantages over Mipmap. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summed area table replaces the X*Y texture, T, with an X*Y set of values, S, where entry x,y in S is the sum of all pixels of T contained in the axis-aligned rectangle from [0,0] to [x, y] inclusive.

Given that you want to compute the average of an arbitrary axis-aligned rectangle of pixels of T, you just need to sample the corner locations in S and do some trivial additions and subtractions. (Hmm. It seems that [wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Summed_area_table) sums (pun intended) this up quite succinctly)

The advantages of the SAT is that it will quickly give you the correct results for any arbitrary axis-aligned rectangle (rather than being limited to power-of-2 squares as in MIP mapping) but

1. You won't get automatic hardware support as you do with MIP maps
2. the SAT can be huge because, assuming you start summing from the top left texel, the bottom right needs to be able to equal the sum of all the texels. For a 1K*1K texture, you'd need 11 extra bits of precision per channel!